# Getting skill did not provide a valid response in alexa development

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am Trying to create a alexa Skill. in lambda function testing i am getting correct response. But in development account testing i am getting error like `The requested skill did not provide a valid response`.

**Lambda Function**:

```
exports.handler =function(event,context){
    // TODO implement
    
    var request = event.request;
    
    if(request.type === "LaunchRequest"){
        let options={};
        options.SpeachText = "Welcome to Wishing Skill.whom you want to wish?"
        options.repromptText = "whom you want to wish?"
        options.endSession = false;
        context.succeed(buildResponse(options));
        
    } else if(request.type === "IntentRequest"){
        let options={};
        if(request.intent.name === "HelloIntent"){
        let name=request.intent.slots.FirstName.value;
        options.SpeachText="Hello "+name+". ";
        options.SpeachText+=getWish();
        options.endSession=false;
        context.succeed(buildResponse(options));
        }else{
            context.fail("Unknown Intent");
        }
        
    }else if(request.type === "IntentRequest"){
        let options={};
        options.SpeachText="Thank you. ";
        context.succeed(buildResponse(options));
    }else{
        context.fail("Unknown Intent Type");
        
    }
};
function getWish(){
    let date= new Date();
    var hours= date.getUTCHours() - 8;
    if(hours<0){
        hours=hours+24;
    }
    if(hours<12){
        return "Good Morning.";
    }else if(hours<18){
        return "Good afternoon.";
    }else{
        return "Good evening.";
    }
};
function buildResponse(options){
    var response= {
      version: "1.0",
      response: {
        outputSpeech: {
          type: "PlainText",
          text: options.SpeachText
        },
        shouldEndSession: options.endSession
      }
    }
    if(options.repromptText){
         response.response.reprompt={
            outputSpeech: {
                type: "PlainText",
                text: options.repromptText
              }
        }
    }
    return response;
};
```

In test response

```
Response
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "PlainText",
      "text": "Hello chandu. Good evening."
    },
    "shouldEndSession": false
  }
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: d05e0869-495f-471b-9c51-3693badd2690 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: d05e0869-495f-471b-9c51-3693badd2690
REPORT RequestId: d05e0869-495f-471b-9c51-3693badd2690  Duration: 18.85 ms  Billed Duration: 19 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 65 MB  Init Duration: 126.07 ms

Request ID
d05e0869-495f-471b-9c51-3693badd2690
```

But when I am trying in developer account it was giving `The requested skill did not provide a valid response`

**[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJgeU.png)**

Please Help me with Some answer. Thankyou in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have to ask you a question before giving my suggestions:
Why do you create the reprompt speech part outside the response to then add it?
I would simply add that part in the creation of the response. Also, I have added more elements in the response json in order to make it more attractive to the user. The card element offers visual response of the alexa device, if it has a screen.

```
function buildSpeechletResponseImage() {
return {
    outputSpeech: {
        type: "PlainText",
        text: "Hello"
    },
    card: {
        type: 'Standard',
        text: "Hellooo",
        image: {
            "smallImageUrl": String("your-image-url.jpg"),
            "largeImageUrl": String("your-image-url.jpg")
        }
    },
    reprompt: {
        outputSpeech: {
            type: 'PlainText',
            text: 'Session will end soon'
        }
    },
    shouldEndSession: false
};
```

}